# Error in cor(exprs(gse), use = "c") : no complete element pairs

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetic-programming

I'm trying to plot a heat map for a "GSE133399", I retrieved the GSE using GEOquery package and then assigned to an object and then tried to plot a heatmap, but I was not successful, I used the following code in RStudio:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
library(GEOquery)
## change my_id to be the dataset that you want.
my_id <- "GSE133399"
gse <- getGEO(my_id)
length(gse)
gse <- gse[[1]]
gse
pData(gse) ## print the sample information
fData(gse) ## print the gene annotation
exprs(gse) ## print the expression data

## exprs get the expression levels as a data frame and get the distribution
summary(exprs(gse))
exprs(gse) <- log2(exprs(gse))
boxplot(exprs(gse),outline=FALSE)
library(dplyr)
sampleInfo <- pData(gse)
sampleInfo
## source_name_ch1 and characteristics_ch1.1 seem to contain factors we might need for the analysis. Let's pick just those columns

sampleInfo <- select(sampleInfo, source_name_ch1,characteristics_ch1.1)

## Optionally, rename to more convenient column names
sampleInfo <- rename(sampleInfo,group = source_name_ch1, patient=characteristics_ch1.1)
sampleInfo
install.packages("pheatmap")
library(pheatmap)
## argument use="c" stops an error if there are any missing data points

corMatrix <- cor(exprs(gse),use="c")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in cor(exprs(gse), use = "c") : no complete element pairs
```

I also  tried this:

```
corMatrix <- cor(exprs(gse),use="c", use="complete.obs")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in cor(exprs(gse), use = "c", use = "complete.obs") : 
  formal argument "use" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I want to achieve this plot:

[image]

Comment: Why did you remove RStudio @MrFlick, I added it because when I run the same code in R on jupyter notebook I get different error! Thank you for edit by the way! but I was hoping someone might encounter the same issue and found a solution.

Comment: There's nothing here that appears to be RStudio specific and the question isn't about the RStudio IDE. Likely you would get the same error if you ran directly in the R GUI. Are all of these lines really required to reproduce the error?

Comment: I see your point @MrFlick, these lines should be reproducible with the same GSE, but I do not understand why I get a different error in R in jupyter notebook, however; I'm interested in R or RStudio to solve the issue.

Comment: I cannot replicate this error with the code you provided. It runs fine for me. Do you see any missing values in your when you run `exprs(gse)`. Have you loaded other packages that are not listed here? (The version with two `use=` parameters doesn't make any sense. You cannot have duplicated parameter names)

Comment: I updated the code, run it again please @MrFlick, I used the standard GSE that with the coding, but I mentioned the the GSE that I used (GSE133399), please try the code with this GSE (GSE133399), thank you for the support

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any expression data included with that accession number. `nrow(exprs(gse))` returns 0. You can't calculate the correlation of nothing.

Comment: It is not about their paper, it is about how to replicate the figure using R @MrFlick

Comment: Try using `my_id <- 'GSE10'`. Your code works correctly on this data set.  As noted by @MrFlick, there doesn't seem to be any expression data included with the GSE133399 accession number.